# How to run rsync with commands chained in it

Tags: linux, rsync

I am sort of perplexed with running commands with rsync

> My scenario:
>
> abc.com xyz.com

abc.com's root public key is added to xyz.com and vice-versa.

However, I am able to do rsync with ordinary user test, but I'd want to execute the command sudo cdsw status on the server xyz.com, and the copy of data has to be happen as well.

From abc.com, I execute the command below

```
sudo rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" /var/lib/cdsw/ xyz.com:/var/lib/cdsw/
```

But I want to execute the sudo cdsw status before rsync on the remote server xyz.com and execute sudo cdsw start, when rsync completes the copy, how do I chain with the above command?

I have tried all the possibilities but nothing worked.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't a `rsync` question... but more of a bash/scripting question.
The `-e` parameter is really only designed to get a shell on a remote server going.  It isn't meant for executing arbitrary commands.
You really only have 2 options that I can think of off the top of my head:

1)  Multiple ssh requests:

```
sudo ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub abc.com cdsw status
sudo rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub abc.com" /var/lib/cdsw/ xyz.com:/var/lib/cdsw/
sudo ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub abc.com cdsw start
```

2)  Create a custom script that is called on login on the remote server:

*/root/custom-rsync.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
function cleanup {
  echo "Starting cdsw"
  cdsw start
}
trap cleanup EXIT
cdsw status
bash
```

and then:

```
sudo rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub abc.com /root/custom-rsync.sh" /var/lib/cdsw/ xyz.com:/var/lib/cdsw/
```

On a side-note... I'm not quite sure why your private-key ends with ".pub".  That is typically supposed-to-be your public key.  Removing the .pub, would allow you to just `sudo ssh abc.com` without having to specify the identity file, as ssh automatically will try to use the id_rsa without asking.